# Finding parameter $k$ for which $\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2= \frac18k^2(x+y+1)^2$ is an equation of an ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I need to find the value of $k$ such that the following equation represents an ellipse:-

$$\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2= \frac18k^2(x+y+1)^2$$

I need to find the range of $k$. Is there any other way than expanding the RHS? Because that would be really tedious and quite a nightmare.

Comment: Consider the definition of an ellipse with respect to one of its foci and its respective directrix.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog I have tried using that but don't really get how to apply it here. Might be missing something, dunno

Comment: Also, expanding the RHS is not too bad, it is $x^2+y^2+1+2x+2y+2xy$.

Comment: You can write this as a conic section with focus $\left(\frac 12, -\frac 12\right)$ and directrix $x+y=-1$

Comment: Expanding isn't so bad. Note that (if you're using the discriminant test $B^2-4AC<0$ for conics of the form $A x^2+B xy+C y^2+D x+E y+F=0$ ) you're only interested in the second-degree terms ($x^2$, $y^2$, $xy$). So, when expanding $(x-1/2)^2$, you can stop at $x^2$, etc.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog Yes but there is $k^2$ multiplied so on taking them all to the left and trying to make squares would be a nightmare

Comment: @Certainlynotadog could you elaborate on how that is the case?

Comment: $k^2=4$ give parabolas, $k=0$ gives a point, my guess would be $k\in (-2,0)\cup (0,2).$

Comment: @Techie5879 see Robert Z’s answer.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog Yes I did have a look. Got my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that [ellipse](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/EllipseFocusDirectrix.shtml) can be characterized as the locus of points $P=(x,y)$ whose distances to a point $F$ and a straight line $d$ are in a fixed ratio less than 1: 
$$\frac{\text{dist}(P, F)}{\text{dist}(P, d)} = c < 1$$
(see also Certainlynotadog's comment above).

In your case, consider $F=(1/2,-1/2)$ and $d$ as $x+y+1=0$. Then the given equation becomes
$$\text{dist}^2(P, F)=\frac{k^2}{4}\text{dist}^2(P, d)$$
and therefore the locus is an ellipse if and only if $k^2/4<1$ that is $|k|<2$. For $k=0$ we have the degenerate case where the ellipse is the point $F$.